# Localising data by directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to localise data in my edit form with the help of the directives.

Input should be:

```
<input translate data-locale="en_EN" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.defaultTranslation.name">
```

My item object is:

```
{
    itemTranslations: [ 
        { name: "item name", locale: "en_EN"}
    ]
}
```

How can I write a directive to display the localised data?

Comment: do you want to choose the locale dynamically, or already have selected locale?

Comment: It is already selected.